# How to get text from selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a project made on Webflow and I need to get a selected product option each time it is changed (in order to use it as a variable).

The structure is the following.

```
<div id="option-set-7df86a9dd26b59b55b2bbb2be9faaecc" data-node-type="commerce-add-to-cart-pill-group" data-commerce-option-set-id="7df86a9dd26b59b55b2bbb2be9faaecc" class="w-commerce-commerceaddtocartoptionpillgroup button-group" role="radiogroup" aria-label="Color">
<div data-node-type="commerce-add-to-cart-pill" class="w-commerce-commerceaddtocartoptionpill product-option-radio-button w--ecommerce-pill-selected" role="radio" aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" data-option-id="6d7cd7a24b43b5d7eddfd97afee8ec6a">
    <div data-wf-bindings="%5B%7B%22innerHTML%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22PlainText%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22identity%22%2C%22params%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%22dataPath%22%3A%22name%22%7D%7D%5D" class="text-block-3">red</div>
</div>
<div data-node-type="commerce-add-to-cart-pill" class="w-commerce-commerceaddtocartoptionpill product-option-radio-button" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" data-option-id="7adea242a3773563cd42cfa783717f4b">
    <div data-wf-bindings="%5B%7B%22innerHTML%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22PlainText%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22identity%22%2C%22params%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%22dataPath%22%3A%22name%22%7D%7D%5D" class="text-block-3">black</div>
</div>
```

In this case I would need to get "red". (Selected option has aria-checked="true".)

Thank in advance!

Comment: try with `$('div[aria-checked="true"]').text()`, this would ofcourse have to be used inside your change event

Comment: Hello, can you provide the wrapper of the selectable products so we can know which event will be triggered whenever the product selected?

Comment: You could probably not use the `aria-` and just go with `$(".w--ecommerce-pill-selected").text()`

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$('.product-option-radio-button[aria-checked="true"]').find('div').eq(0).text()
```

Comment: No need for `.find('div').eq(0)` as `.text()` combines all the text from child elements and there's only one child element.